# Mechanics of a spinning cup

Tags: classical-mechanics

Has anyone noticed how if you have a plastic cup on its side, and you spin it from either side, you can get it to stand upright? Well you can see some guy try it on this (fairly odd) [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITEgPsOubDI). Depending on which side you spin it from you can get it to stand either right-side up or upside down. I've never quite been able to figure out what's going on physically. Any insights would be appreciated. It seems important that if you spin it from different ends, it ends up differently.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone cares, after some more research, it seems this is a surprisingly difficult problem to nail down precisely, e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020746216000421. There's an attempt at a qualitative explanation towards the end of the paper.